# Засветы между тайлами в 2d платформере

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d, шейдеры

Делаю 2d платформер в Unity3d 5.3.6. Уровень строится из спрайтов 32*32 пикселя, соответственно 1 юнит на 1 юнит. Скейл 1*1*1. Спрайты (игровые объекты со SpriteRender) расставлены на координатах равным целым числам. Сглаживание в настройках движка отключено. Но время от времени появляются в окне игры и в SceneView вот такие засветы между тайлами: [image: засветы]

Пробовал включать в стандартном спрайт шейдере pixel snap - не помогло.[image: Материал для SpriteRender со стандартным спрайтовым шейдером] Стало даже хуже - между анимированными покадровой спрайтовой анимацией игровыми объектами такой просвет стал появляться постоянно. В сети не нашёл бесплатных шейдеров для решения этой проблемы, а сам шейдеры писать почти не умею.

Comment: Если зайти Edit -> Project Settings -> Quality. то Anti Aliasing включен или выключен? Если включен, то попробуйте выключить...... также убедитесь что разрешение экрана содержит четные числа, т.е. не 401x501, а 400x500 к примеру

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Anti Aliasing выключен в Project Settings. С разрешением экрана не очень ясно что делать: Игру разрабатываю под UWP, а там экраны могут быть вообще любыми. Как средствами Unity3d задавать фиксированное разрешение экрана для UWP не ясно, вот для stand alone приложений это есть в Project Settings => player. А мне получается нужно написать скрипт для камеры с фиксацией разрешения экрана? Впрочем даже если написать скрипт для камеры, то в sceneview проблема сохранится

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, кстати, разрешение обязательно фиксировать таким низким или подойдет любое кратное 2м?

Comment: я же написал `убедитесь что разрешение экрана содержит четные числа` =)  то есть да, кратное двум

Comment: нашел некоторые советы ..... https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/tile-map-tearing-problems.225777/#post-1507246   ..... попробуйте что-то из этого

Comment: 1. придётся переделывать вообще все спрайты и спрайтшиты для анимаций - слишком долго потом читать
2. Уже соблюдено размер спрайтов 32*32 и настройки импорта 32*32
3. Невозможно присваивать позиции камеры целочисленные значения, поскольку она следит за игроком
4. Это поломает работу встроенной в юнити физики
5. Выставление разрешения кратного 2м не решает проблему
8. Pixel snap тоже не помогает